# SQL Server - Adding Primary and Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one query that creates several tables, listed below, and a second query that is supposed to add Primary and Foreign keys to each. However, when I try executing my query, I'm greeted with the following error messages:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'DEPARTMENT' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__EMPLOYEE__dno__25869641'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I'm not sure what this means, as I have researched both primary and foreign keys. Can anyone lead me in the right direction as to how to solve this issue? Thanks! :)

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
(
    fname       varchar(100),
    minit       char(1),
    lname       varchar(100),
    ssn         char(9),
    bdate       date,
    addr        varchar(100),
    sex         char(1),
    salary      int,
    super_ssn   char(9),
    dno         int
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT 
(
    dname           varchar(100),
    dnumber         int,
    mgr_ssn         char(9),
    mgr_start_date  date
);

CREATE TABLE DEPENDENTS 
(
    essn            char(9),
    dependent_name  varchar(100),
    sex             char(1),
    bdate           date,
    relationship    varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPT_LOCATIONS 
(
    dnumber         int,
    dlocation       varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT 
(
    pname       varchar(100),
    pnumber     int,
    plocation   varchar(100),
    dnum        int
);

CREATE TABLE WORKS_ON 
(
    essn    char(9),
    pno     int,
    hrs     float
);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD PRIMARY KEY(ssn);
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD FOREIGN KEY(super_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ssn);
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD FOREIGN KEY(dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(dnumber);

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD PRIMARY KEY(dnumber);
ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY(mgr_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ssn);

ALTER TABLE DEPT_LOCATIONS ADD PRIMARY KEY(dnumber, dlocation);
ALTER TABLE DEPT_LOCATIONS ADD FOREIGN KEY(dnumber) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(dnumber);

ALTER TABLE PROJECT ADD PRIMARY KEY(pnumber);
ALTER TABLE PROJECT ADD FOREIGN KEY(dnum) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(dnumber);

ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON ADD PRIMARY KEY(essn, pno); 
ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON ADD FOREIGN KEY(essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ssn);
ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON ADD FOREIGN KEY(pno) REFERENCES PROJECT(pnumber);

ALTER TABLE DEPENDENTS ADD PRIMARY KEY(essn, dependent_name);
ALTER TABLE DEPENDENTS ADD FOREIGN KEY(essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ssn);
```

Comment: Primary key column should be non null able. For example change Employee table ssn char(9) should be changed as ssn char(9) not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary key column should be non null able. Table definition should have not null for all PKs.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    fname       varchar(100),
    minit       char(1),
    lname       varchar(100),
    ssn         char(9) not null,
    bdate       date,
    addr        varchar(100),
    sex         char(1),
    salary      int,
    super_ssn   char(9),
    dno         int
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
    dname           varchar(100),
    dnumber         int not null,
    mgr_ssn         char(9),
    mgr_start_date  date
);

CREATE TABLE DEPENDENTS (
    essn            char(9) not null,
    dependent_name  varchar(100) not null,
    sex             char(1),
    bdate           date,
    relationship    varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPT_LOCATIONS (
    dnumber         int not null,
    dlocation       varchar(100) not null
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
    pname       varchar(100),
    pnumber     int not null,
    plocation   varchar(100),
    dnum        int
);

CREATE TABLE WORKS_ON (
    essn    char(9) not null,
    pno     int not null,
    hrs     float
);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD PRIMARY KEY(ssn);
ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD PRIMARY KEY(dnumber);
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD FOREIGN KEY(super_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ssn);
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD FOREIGN KEY(dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(dnumber);


ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY(mgr_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ssn);

ALTER TABLE DEPT_LOCATIONS ADD PRIMARY KEY(dnumber, dlocation);
ALTER TABLE DEPT_LOCATIONS ADD FOREIGN KEY(dnumber) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(dnumber);

ALTER TABLE PROJECT ADD PRIMARY KEY(pnumber);
ALTER TABLE PROJECT ADD FOREIGN KEY(dnum) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(dnumber);

ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON ADD PRIMARY KEY(essn, pno); 
ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON ADD FOREIGN KEY(essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ssn);
ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON ADD FOREIGN KEY(pno) REFERENCES PROJECT(pnumber);

ALTER TABLE DEPENDENTS ADD PRIMARY KEY(essn, dependent_name);
ALTER TABLE DEPENDENTS ADD FOREIGN KEY(essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ssn);
```

Comment: `SSN` is a really bad choice for a PK, since it's ***NOT*** guaranteed to be unique! There *can be* duplicates!

Comment: @marc_s: It is also **illegal** to use SSN as a unique identifier, in both Canada and USA.